# Symfony multisite architecture without using CMF

Tags: php, symfony, service, routes, multisite

I'm trying to create an opensource application that can handle a sort of multi-site architecture with plugins ( bundles ).

To have: **Single source code** with **different db connections on different databases with same structure** and **dynamically prefixed routes for each site**

to handle multiple db connections on same service i've thought to define, via php, multiple service IDs that point to the same class:

```
$container->setDefinition('app.service_site1', new Definition(
    MyService::class,
));

$container->setDefinition('app.service_site2', new Definition(
    MyService::class,
));
```

So i can have

```
$this->get("service_".$site)
```

taking advantages of global singletons at same time.

Then, to handle routing i'm trying to implement a custom [route loader](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html) to have an optional prefix that specify the site alias ( site1, site2 ) to select correct service when we've to retrieve data.

**Question1:** Is this a good practice?

**Question2:** if yes, how can i differentiate db connection with this kind of solution?

**Question3:** How can i set an optional route prefix via php? i'm trying this to test:

```
    $app = $this->import('@AppBundle/Controller/', 'annotation');
    $app->addPrefix("/{prefix}");
    $app->addDefaults(array("prefix" => "def"));
```

But it doesn't work